# Razor view disabled html attribute based on viewmodel property

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor

I want to set an html disabled attribute based on a viewmodel property.

I wrote:

```
<button disabled="@Model.prop">Button</button>
```

This works, but I'm not sure why. When true, it sets disabled="disabled", I would expect it to set disabled="True" which would disable the element by setting the disabled attribute at all. When false, the disabled attribute is entirely gone, whereas I would expect disabled="False" and for this to also disable the element.

I don't understand how this is being evaluated on the server when it generates the view so I was hoping someone could help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html disabled attribute not need set a value, if you set `disabled="true"` or `disabled="false"` both ways gonna disabled just because have the disabled attribute and that's why razor when its false remove the attribute

[see the reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)

Example

```html
<input type="text" disabled="true" value="true">
<input type="text" disabled="false" value="false">
<input type="text" disabled value="just attribute">
<input type="text" value="without attribute">
```

Comment: Interesting. I was aware that the disabled attr should be enabled regardless of the actual value included, but I was unaware that Razor would recognize that I'm throwing a boolean to the disabled prop and just remove it for me.

Comment: It also works with null. If the value of an attribute is null, Razor won't include it at all.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help!